# How I can read sent message from Masstransit Middle ware/Filter class

Tags: masstransit

I have middleware/Filter like following

```
public class TestFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : class, PipeContext
{
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context){}

    public async Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
    {
        var requestInfo = Program.Container.GetInstance<RequestInfo>();
        //How i can access sent message from middleware
        requestInfo.Token = "some value from message" + "Some Value from Middleware";
    }
}
```

Now I want to read sent message from the Send method of TestFilter. How I can achieve this. Expecting your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am thinking MassTransit is going to add new attribute called "**Message**" to their context. Right now I am using version 3.5.7 and Message is not available there. Hope next version will release soon. And then we can get message from middleware.

Following is the value of context from middleware.
[image]

Thank you very much to MassTransit and @Alexey Zimarev for new version of masstransit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PipeContext.TryGetPayload<T>(out T payload)`

```
MyMessage message;
context.TryGetPayload(out message);
```

I know this work for consume context but not sure about send/publish context.

However, if you just want to get some values from the sent message, you can better use observers. There are specific observers for send and publish. [Here is the documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/observers.html#observing-sent-messages) about it.

Comment: Thank you very much for response. But I am getting null here. And it returns false.

Comment: I will set Claims Principal from middleware based on sent message. If I set claims from middleware then it is available in Consumer but if I Set it from observer then claims is not available from the consumer. So I need to set claims from middleware and use it from the consumer.